# How do I add the manufacturer attribute to sales_flat_order_item?

Tags: sales-order, flat-catalog

Hi we use the manufacturer attribute a lot. And often in code we have to grab it separately because it is stored as a product attribute.

**question:** Is it possible, just like the flat_catalog tables, to add the manufacturer attribute to the `sales_flat_order_item` table?

Comment: you can add it as sku or product name but make sure try with some other attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947179/how-to-add-product-specific-attribute-column-to-sales-flat-order-item-table

(general answer that can apply)